# how do I set up RPush in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, push

I'm a bit confused on how to do some of the config for Rpush when starting from the Rails environment.  If I just want to Rpush.embed and run within this same process, where should I call Rpush.embed?  Does this go in the initializer?  I am also unclear on the best place to set up my apps.  I see there is a nice feature for signaling rpush to re-read from the configured app, but where do I configure the app itself?  I see that I can do this with active model calls, but I obviously don't want to create a new app everytime I start the rack (or rails).

Comment: hi @deepwinter can u help me with Rpush. 
Ryt now in my app i have set up all basic things..like device token and all and also in database i have 1 notification. Now how to send this to app users

Comment: hi @NidhinSG please post another question and direct me to, and i'll paste some code there.  it just won't format well in this comment! glad to help.

Comment: hey here is one i posted a few days ago

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161522/sending-notification-to-app-using-rpush-gem-ruby-on-rails?noredirect=1#comment37289952_24161522

Answer (score 2):

Create apps using database migration, put Rpush.embed in config.ru