# Sending Notification to App using Rpush Gem Ruby on Rails

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Im trying to implement Push notification in my app using Rpush Gem.
This is so far i have tried.

```
    if @push_notification.present?
    else
      app = Rpush::Apns::App.new
      app.name = "ios_app"
      app.certificate = File.read("config/apns-dev.pem")
      app.environment = "development" # APNs environment.
      app.password = ""
      app.connections = 1
      app.save! 
    end

    n = Rpush::Apns::Notification.new
    n.app = Rpush::Apns::App.find_by_name("ios_app")
    n.device_token = session[:push_notification_token]
    n.alert = "hi im alert!"
    n.data = { foo: :bar }
    n.save!
```

this save a notification to the database. I want to know how to send this notification.

Comment: send via email? pop up?

Comment: like usual notification on IOS apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using rpush this should be working to send your push message actually.  there is the possibility that your certificates are not set up right, or that the push token is incorrect, or that perhaps you have not started rpush.  Do you call Rpush.embed somewhere in your stack?  I have placed this in config.ru

Comment: hey can you help me out

Comment: hey rpush was running. n i ran it in foreground. in console i got message that 4 notification got sent to token.
I dont know anythign about Rpush.ember

Comment: in this case, your problem is either with the token you are sending from your device, or with the pem file (certificate) not matching the provisioning profile used to the deploy the application to your devices.

Comment: I don't think so, .embed is just another way of running rpush.  I think it's your provisioning profiles.

Comment: Thanks for the help deepwinter.. I think Rpush is not known to many... My problem was with the certificate. Made new one. Now its working fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm able to save the notifications. but i don't know that whether they are being sent or not. How to check if they were pushed or not?

Comment: you can check the rpush_notifications table in the database to see details of what is happening.